# Need help reading xml file in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, linq-to-xml

I am making a program for Windows phone that will get weather data from a xml file and display it on screen. However, I keep getting null values and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Sample XML file: http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=44.52160&lon=-87.98980&FcstType=dwml

Here is what I have:

```
try
{
    // get the stream containing the response from the async call
    streamResult = forecastState.AsyncResponse.GetResponseStream();

    // load the XML
    XElement xmlWeather = XElement.Load(streamResult);

    // find the source element
    XElement xmlCurrent = xmlWeather.Descendants("source").First();

    // get city and height
    xmlCurrent = xmlWeather.Descendants("location").First();
    mTempCityName = (string)(xmlCurrent.Element("city"));
    mTempHeight = (int)(xmlCurrent.Element("height"));

    //Find the forecast time
    xmlCurrent = xmlWeather.Descendants("time-layout").First();

    //store time of day in array
    mTimeOfDay = (string)(xmlCurrent.Attribute("period-name"));

    //Find the temperature
    xmlCurrent = xmlWeather.Descendants("temperature").First();
    mTemp = (int)(xmlCurrent.Element("value"));

    //now get the current weather conditions for each time period
    xmlCurrent = xmlWeather.Descendants("weather").First();
    mDescription = (string)(xmlCurrent.Attribute("weather-summary"));

    //now get icon links for weather
    xmlCurrent = xmlWeather.Descendants("conditions-icon").First();
    mIcon = (string)(xmlCurrent.Attribute("icon-link"));
}
```

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as "csharp". The language is named "C#".

Comment: Do you get null values for all your values?

Comment: Actually I was able to get the city name and height but I get null values for the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well:

- `time-layout` doesn't have an attribute called `period-name` (it has subelements with that attribute)
- temperature should be okay, I think
- `weather` doesn't have a `weather-summary` attribute - it has subelements with that attribute
- `conditions-icon` doesn't have an `icons-link` attribute, it has `icons-link` elements

In other words, for each bit you need to look at exactly what the XML contains, and then exactly what you're asking for, being careful to distinguish between elements and attributes.

Note that for the values you're casting to `int` (which don't need extra brackets around them, btw) you should be getting an exception in this case - you clearly can't be getting actual null values. Is it possible that an exception is being thrown and you're not noticing it? What's in your catch block?

Comment: In fact, why not remove the try/catch block entirely?

Comment: The values that are being cast as int are being assigned to int variables so they don't throw an exception.

Comment: @SEAlink: But they should throw an exception if it can't find the relevant attribute/element, which is what's happening elsewhere.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: The debugger isn't throwing an exception even with the try/catch block removed...